# VSCode REST Client : how make my request being captured by fiddler Classic

Tags: rest, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, fiddler, vscode-restclient

Using VSCode Rest Client , my request does not appears on fiddler Classic for windows

I am using request

.vscode/settings.json

```
"baseUrl": "http://localhost:"
```

base.http

```
GET {{baseUrl}}
```

And getting an answere

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Sat, 16 Dec 2023 10:48:53 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

But fiddler with default settings does not show  the request

I tried to use a proxy

```
//.vscode/settings.json
"proxy": "http://localhost:8888"
// base.http
GET {{baseUrl}}
Proxy: {{proxy}}
```

It does not change anything, fiddler doesn't seem to see the request
[image: fiddler requests]

Do you know how to make fiddler see this kind of request made by rest client for vs code?

Comment: I believe VS's setting is `http.proxy`, not `proxy` or `base.http`

Comment: If I remember correctly, localhost connections are by default bypassed in Fiddler Classic. See HTTPS interception options in Fiddler.